# What does "見てけらしょ" mean?

Tags: meaning, dialects

What does "見てけらしょ" mean?　This is the full sentence:

> 見てけらしょ、おやじさん。なんだかお伽話しみたいだべさ。

(It is from the book 鉄道員 written by 浅田次郎.)

This is the previous sentence for more context:

> かつては無蓋貨車と機関車で犇めいていた貨物ヤードは、涯もない雪原だった。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think most native speakers would understand it as a dialectal form for 見てください even if they have never heard it or don’t know what dialect it is. (I haven't and don't, but it sounds like a northern dialect to me.)

見てけろ is another possible form. You might find it easier to guess because it sounds closer to the imperative 見てくれ.

Comment: So are you figuring that けらしょ derives from a contraction of くれ + ましょう, or something like that?

Comment: Ya, as Karl asks, any insight into derivation would be lovely.  

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi - I don't know. It just sounds similar to some of the variations for ください I know from different dialects such as くれんさい and くらっせ. I think the /s/ or /sh/ sound is related to なされ. I see no connection with ましょう.